# Condition “$\exists \rho, \alpha>0$ s.t. $I[u]\geq \alpha$ if $\|u\|=\rho$” in Mountain Pass replaced by “$0$ is a strict local minimum of $I$”.

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

The [Mountain Pass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem) (see also Evans’ [Partial Differential Equations](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewclw8181/wffc.files/Partial%20Differential%20Equations.Evans.pdf), section 8.5) is stated like this:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $I: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a
> $C^1$-functional satisfying the [Palais–Smale
> condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palais%E2%80%93Smale_compactness_condition)
> and $I[0]=0$. Suppose
>
> (A) $\exists \rho, \alpha>0$ such that $I[u]\geq \alpha$ if $\|u\|=\rho$,
>
> (B) $\exists v \in X$ with $\|v\|>\rho$ such that $I[v] \leq 0$.
>
> Then $I$ has a
> critical value $c \geq \alpha$ and $c$ is characterized by $$
>   c=\inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \max _{t\in [0,1]} I[\gamma(t)] $$ where $$
>  \Gamma=\{\gamma \in C([0,1], X) \mid \gamma(0)=0, \gamma(1)=v\} $$

**I want to ask that** whether the condition (A) can be replaced by that “$0$ is a **strict** local minimum”? Because by geometric thinking, this is possibly true.

Comment: Maybe you could add details about the proof of what you wrote above

Comment: If $c=0$, then the statement is obviously true, since $0$ is a critical point. It's hard to imagine a functional $I$ that does not satisfy $(A)$, *and* such that $c>0$. It could be worth trying to construct such a functional in a simple case and see if you can find a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I mean that since the $0$ is a strict local minimum. then there must be a $\sigma$ that if $\|u\| \le \sigma$ then $I[u] \geq \alpha >0$, which is the condition $(A)$.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, strict local minimum is not enough to imply (A). In $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, consider $I(x):=\|ax\|_{\ell^2}^2-\|ax\|_{\ell^2}^4$, where with $ax$ I denote the componentwise product of $x$ and the sequence $a$ given by $a_k=1/(1+k)$, or any other sequence that converges to zero. The origin is a strict local minimum, but (A) does not hold, essentially because you can make $\|ax\|$ arbitrarily small with constraint $\|x\|=R$, with $R>0$ fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample! Actually I'm reading a paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5231 , which solved the higher order mean-field equation by mountain pass technique, $0$ being the strict local minimum and $\exists v \in X$ with $\|v\|>\rho$ such that $I[v] \leq 0$ suggest that the mountain pass might be applied, then he started constructing P-S sequence.

Comment: In the theorem, the authors stated that $0$ must be the strict local minimum, it seems that only when $0$ is the strict local minimum could they have the mountain pass structure.